# Making if Statement reactive in Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, ace-editor

I am new to meteor. I started using sessions for making the content reactive between different templates to use. I am also using Ace text editor in my application. It has some configuration Settings:

```
Template.template_containing_AceTextEditor.configuration = function(){
      return function(editor){
                    if (Session.get('text') == "something") //here I want it to be reactive
                    {          
                       //do something every time 'text' changes
                    }
      }

}
```

and I also dont want to lose Template.template_containing_AceTextEditor.configuration because it is connected to a package I am using.

Comment: Have you tried using helpers? Once you define your helper (which is reactive) you can use it in handlebars with __{{#if something}}__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can make code reactive in several ways, one is putting the reactive code in the `Tracker.autorun`.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if (Session.get('text') == "something") //this will run every time session text changes
     {          
       //do something every time 'text' changes
     }
})
```

Make sure you load tracker into your project.